# Error when connecting to Azure SQL database. The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)

Tags: sql-server, connection, timeout, azure-sql-database

In my company we are using Azure SQL database as our internal data storage. All of my team members are using the same login and password to get access to database. There is no issue when they are trying to connect or update database.

I am new employee, my manager granted me an access to the same database. As per company policy all of laptops in company have the same configuration, moreover system is installed from one backup image. When I am trying to connect the same database with the same login and password it occur below error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> ---
>
> Cannot connect to xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net.
>
> ---

```
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=121&LinkId=20476
```

I took some of these tips http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325487 to try fix error but it not helped.
Network adapter drivers were updated.
Port 1433 was added to inbound and outbound rules in "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" feature.

I contacted our internal support, but they do not know reason of this error.

Comment: Can you set "Connection Timeout=60"  and test again?

Answer (score 1):

Error 121 has always been considered a network related error as you can read in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325487/advanced-network-adapter-troubleshooting-for-windows-workstations) Microsoft Support article.

> Network connectivity problems have various causes, but they typically
>   occur because of incorrect network adapters, incorrect switch
>   settings, faulty hardware, or driver issues. Some connectivity
>   symptoms are intermittent and do not clearly point to any one of these
>   causes.
>
> Typical error messages include the following:
>
> Error 121: "The semaphore timeout period has expired"
>   (ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT).

If you are getting connected from home to the corporate network, please consider examine the Internet service you receive. Make sure you are getting the computer successfully connected to the VPN.

Please compare the network adapter settings in your computer with network adapters of other computers in your organization. A driver update may have changed settings.

If you are using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) to connect to Azure SQL Database, please consider to click the "Options" button of SQL Server Management Studio, on the "Connection Properties" tab, try setting a greater value for the "Connection time-out" setting. If you are using a different tool to connect to Azure SQL Database look for a timeout setting and increase the value.